# Weird xDomain issues with $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, topsy

I am trying to use Topsy for tracking some stats.  I had a script that worked locally, that uses $.getJSON to get what I need from their api.

Now I have run into a problem after deploying I get origin not allowed I have tried just about everything I know to get their JSONP to interpret

the code that works locally

```
get_total = (trend, duration, callback) ->
  requests = []
  search_words = []
  if trend.total?
    callback(trend, trend.total)
  else
    for item in trend.search_terms
      search_words.push(item.term)
    keywords = search_words.join('+OR+')
    url = "http://otter.topsy.com/search.json?callback=test&q=#{keywords}&window=#{duration}&apikey=38A260E9D12A4908B1AF9184B691131"
    requests.push($.getJSON(url, (data) ->
        trend.total = data.response.total
    ))

    $.when.apply($, requests).then ->
      callback(trend, trend.total)
```

When I remove the param for `&callback` and add a `?` I get parse errors and the json is still sent with a MIME type json rather than a script.

according to the Topsy API adding a callback is all you need to serve a script instead of json.

### [Topsy JSONP Refrence](http://code.google.com/p/otterapi/wiki/ResponseFormats#Javascript_(JSONP))

> ### Javascript (JSONP)
>
> When an API request uses a Javascript response format, the response body will be a javascript function call that takes one parameter containing the response object. An HTTP Header Content-Type: application/javascript` will also be sent.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   Name      |  Type    |  Description                                   |
+-------------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
|   callback  |  string  |  Javascript callback function name. (required) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: hmm... i can't get topsy to return jsonp. so far all it returns is json. i tried this url:
http://otter.topsy.com/search.json?callback=test&q=test&apikey=38A260E9D12A4908B1AF9184B691131

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this url:

http://otter.topsy.com/search.js?callback=test&q=test&apikey=38A260E9D12A4908B1AF9184B691131

Note, i changed it from search.json to search.js

Comment: I just figured this out right before your answer... I hate the little things